# I'm in need of help checking my code. Any reviewing is greatly apreciated

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This is the driver code provided by my instructor, It isn't meant to be edited by me.

***PlayingCardTest.cpp***:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "PlayingCard.h"

PlayingCard makeValidCard(int value, int suit);

int main()
{
    // Create a playing card
    PlayingCard card1;

    // Test the default constructor and GetCardCode
    std::cout << "Testing default constructor. Expect card code to be 00\n card code is :";
    std::cout << card1.getCardCode() << std::endl << std::endl;

    // Test the setter and getter
    std::cout << "Seting card to 'AH' using SetValue and SetSuit" << std::endl;
    card1.setCard('A', 'H');
    std::cout << "GetValue returns :" << card1.getValue() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GetSuit returns :" << card1.getSuit() << std::endl << std::endl;

    // Test overloaded constructor
    PlayingCard tenOfSpades('T', 'S');
    std::cout << "Testing overloaded constructor. Expect card code to be TS\n card code is :";
    std::cout << tenOfSpades.getCardCode() << std::endl << std::endl;

    // Test IsValid with valid cards
    std::cout << "Testing valid card codes.\n"
        << "Expect isValid to return true for all (except perhaps Jokers.)"
        << std::endl;
    // Create and test valid cards
    int validCards = 0;     // cards that return true for IsValid
    int invalidCards = 0;   // cards that return false for IsValid

    // Create and test four suits plus the jokers
    for(int suit = 1; suit <= 5; suit++)
    {
        // Create and test ace, 2 - 9, Jack, Queen, and King
        for(int value = 1; value <= 13; value++)
        {
            PlayingCard aCard = makeValidCard(value, suit);
            std::cout << "Card Code: " << aCard.getCardCode() << " IsValid :";
            if (aCard.isValid())
            {
                validCards++;
                std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                invalidCards++;
                std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
            }
            // suit 5 is just for creating the two Jokers
            if (suit == 5 && value >= 2)
                break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "IsValid returned false for " << invalidCards << " card codes" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "IsValid returned true for " << validCards << " card codes" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Test IsValid with invalid cards
    // Create and test invalid cards
    std::cout << "Testing invalid card codes; isValid should return false for all." << std::endl;
    validCards = 0;
    invalidCards = 0;
    // Loop through all possible ASCII character codes for card codes
    for(int suit = 0; suit <= 255; suit++)
        for(int value = 0; value <= 255; value++)
        {
            // Only check card codes that are not valid
            PlayingCard aCard = makeValidCard(value, suit);
            if (aCard.getCardCode() == "00")
            {
                if (aCard.isValid())
                {
                    std::cout << "value :" << value << " suit :" <<suit << " IsValid :";
                    std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
                    validCards++;
                }
                else
                {
                    invalidCards++;
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << "IsValid returned false for " << invalidCards << " card codes" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "IsValid returned true for " << validCards << " card codes" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

/******************************************************/
/* Test Functions                                     */
/******************************************************/

PlayingCard makeValidCard(int iValue, int iSuit)
{
    char value = '0';
    char suit = '0';

    switch (iValue)
    {
    case 1:
        value = 'A';
        break;
    case 10:
        value = 'T';
        break;
    case 11:
        value = 'J';
        break;
    case 12:
        value = 'Q';
        break;
    case 13:
        value = 'K';
        break;
    default:
        if ((iValue >= 2) && (iValue <= 9))
            value = '0' + iValue;
        break;
    }

    switch (iSuit)
    {
    case 1:
        suit = 'D';
        break;
    case 2:
        suit = 'S';
        break;
    case 3:
        suit = 'C';
        break;
    case 4:
        suit = 'H';
        break;
    // Special case for the Joker
    case 5:
        if(iValue == 1)
        {
            value = 'Z';
            suit = 'B';
        }
        else if(iValue == 2)
        {
            value = 'Z';
            suit = 'R';
        }
        else
        {
            value = '0';
            suit = '0';
        }
        break;
    }

    PlayingCard testCard(value, suit);
    return testCard;
}
```

This is my header file, ***PlayingCard.h***:

```
#ifndef PLAYINGCARD_H_INCLUDED
#define PLAYINGCARD_H_INCLUDED

class PlayingCard
{
private:
    char suit, value;

public:
    PlayingCard(){suit = '0'; value = '0';}
    PlayingCard(char myValue, char mySuit);

    char getValue() {return value;}
    char getSuit() {return suit;}

    std::string getCardCode();
    bool setCard(char myValue, char mySuit);
    bool isValid();

#endif // PLAYINGCARD_H_INCLUDED
```

And this is my class implementation file, ***PlayingCard.cpp***:

```
#include "PlayingCard.h"

PlayingCard::PlayingCard (char myValue, char mySuit)
{
    char aValue[13] ('2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K','A'))
    char aSuit[4] {'D','H','C','S']

    for(count = 0; count <= 12; count++)
    {
        if (myValue = aValue[count])
        {
            for (count2 = 0; count2 <= 3; count2++)
            {
                if (mySuit = aSuit[count2++])
                {
                    suit = mySuit;
                    value = myValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

bool PlayingCard::setCard(char myValue, char mySuit)
{
    char aValue[13] ('2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K','A'))
    char aSuit[4] {'D','H','C','S']

    for(count = 0; count <= 12; count++)
    {
        if (myValue = aValue[count])
        {
            for (count2 = 0; count2 <= 3; count2++)
            {
                if (mySuit = aSuit[count2++])
                {
                    suit = mySuit;
                    value = myValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

string PlayingCard::getCardCode()
{
    return suit + value;
}

bool PlayingCard::isValid()
{
    char aValue[13] ('2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K','A'))
    char aSuit[4] {'D','H','C','S']

    for(count = 0; count <= 12; count++)
    {
        if (myValue = aValue[count])
        {
            for (count2 = 0; count2 <= 3; count2++)
            {
                if (mySuit = aSuit[count2++])
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the compiler errors I'm getting. I'm not sure what to do, it looks like they are in the file I shouldn't edit. I would really appreciate help you can give.

> PlayingCardTest.cpp|103|error: 'PlayingCard PlayingCard::makeValidCard(int, int)' cannot be overloaded|
>
> PlayingCardTest.cpp|5|error: with 'PlayingCard PlayingCard::makeValidCard(int, int)'|
>
> PlayingCardTest.cpp|169|error: expected '}' at end of input|
>
> PlayingCardTest.cpp|169|error: expected unqualified-id at end of input|
>
> ||=== Build finished: 4 errors, 0 warnings ===|

Comment: You might want to try asking over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Actually, this is off topic at code review.  Code review is for improving existing, working code.  His code wasn't compiling, and helping with compilation errors is only on topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First round of comments:

1. Style nit: order sections "public", "protected", then "private". Private section should not go before public. This is not technically required, but is fairly standard practice.
2. Style nit: declare each variable using a separate statement, each on its own line. Using commas is  a good way to get in trouble (e.g. when declaring pointer types) and is poor style.
3. Use an initialization list in the constructor rather than using the assignment operator.
4. You should include "<string>" in your header to use std::string.

Second round of comments:

1. You are initializing your arrays weirdly; you should use {} as the brackets.
2. You do not need to specify the size of the arrays in the initialization.
3. Style nit: do not use magic constants like "12" in your code. Instead, assign them to a variable such as value_length or value_count, and use the named variable.
4. Did you mean to do an equals comparison ("==") or an assignment ("=") in your if-statement? If you meant to do an assignment, you should probably move it outside of the if.

Third round of comments:

1. You unnecessarily duplicate code between your non-default constructor and your setCard function. You should be able to share code between those two functions. Since setCard is not a virtual function, you should be able to simply call it from your constructor.
2. Your setCard logic seems fairly complicated. Most "set" functions are much more trivial than that. You should consider adding documentation explaining the logic of what it is trying to do.
3. The "getValue()", "getCardCode()", "getSuit()", and "isValid()" functions should be declared "const".

Fourth round of comments:

1. Since your professor does "PlayingCard card = makeValidCard(....)", it is clear that he wants your card class to support assignment. Since your "setCard()" function and your non-default constructor do something other than simply set the attributes, it would make sense to provide a "PlayingCard& operator=(const PlayingCard&);" assignment operator as well as a "PlayingCard::PlayingCard(const PlayingCard&)" copy constructor. If you do not provide these, it is good practice to add a comment to the effect that copying using the default assignment / copy has been intentionally allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `};` at the end of your header file.